# Minimal Libre Office install to convert MS files to PDF

Tags: linux, pdf-generation, libreoffice

Does anyone have the minimum list of necessary Libre Office files to convert Microsoft .doc, .xls files to PDF? I'm planning to run the conversions programatically and GUI-less as follow: `soffice -headless -convert-to pdf [inputfile]`

My sysadmin does not want to install the entire Libre Office suite for security reasons.

Of course, if anyone of you knows of another way to convert MS docs to PDF on Linux I'm all ears.

Thank you.

Comment: When I looked into this a while ago, because the bulk of OpenOffice/LibreOffice was "core/shared" code, you gained almost nothing by trying to install parts of it, so typically to be avoided.  Docmosis can do doc->pdf using a cloud service so you don't have to install anything.  It doesn't do xls->pdf though.  (please note I work for the company).